# How to add an item in a collection using Linq and C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics

I have a collection of objects. e.g.

```
List<Subscription> subscription = new List<Subscription>
{
    new Subscription{ Type = "Trial", Type = "Offline", Period = 30  },
    new Subscription{ Type = "Free",  Type = "Offline", Period = 90  },
    new Subscription{ Type = "Paid",  Type = "Online",  Period = 365 }
};
```

Now I want to add one more item in this list using LINQ. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to use LINQ? Why not just `subscription.Add(new Subscription());` ?

Comment: Yes you guys are right. We cannot add an item using LINQ. Now I am doing same as Grant and Jon said.

Comment: subscription.Add(new Subscription { Type = "Foo", Type2 = "Bar", Period = 1 });

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't. LINQ is for *querying*, not adding. You add a new item by writing:

```
subscription.Add(new Subscription { Type = "Foo", Type2 = "Bar", Period = 1 });
```

(Note that you can't specify the property `Type` twice in the same object initializer.)

This isn't using LINQ at all - it's using object initializers and the simple `List<T>.Add` method.

Comment: There are kinda exceptions to this. For example needing to append an empty ListItem to a collection for the purposes of display. In this scenario you can accomplish this with a Union as such StockCollection.Union(new[] { new Stock() { Name = "" } }). While this is certainly not a great practice sometimes its useful.

Comment: I've used it like this in MVC @Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.StockID, Model.Stock.Union(new[] { new Stock() { Name = "" } }).Select(o => new SelectListItem() { Text = o.Name, Value = o.StockID.ToString() })

Comment: @MaximGershkovich: That isn't appending a list item to a collection. It's creating a new sequence out of two sequences. (Personally I'd use `Concat` rather than `Union`, but that's a different matter.) "Adding an item to a collection" necessarily changes the contents of the collection - you're not doing that.

Comment: Fair enough but I feel like that's arguing about semantics rather than the actual intent of the OP.

Comment: @Maxim: the intent of the OP seems to be adding to a collection, given that that's what was asked for. Union simply doesn't do that.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using `List.Add()`:

```
subscription.Add(new Subscriptioin(...))
```

LINQ `Union()` overkill by wrapping a single item by a `List<>` instance:

```
subscriptions.Union(new List<Subscription> { new Subscriptioin(...) };
```

Comment: To elaborate on the second approach, it's the functional approach which treats modified versions of lists as new instances. This allows list immutability and has certain inherent advantages in functional programming model. It may not be as performant though depending on the scenario. For further reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object