# How to Update an item in a collection using and C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

Some times ago I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648664/how-to-add-an-item-in-a-collection-using-linq-and-c/7648711#7648711) "How to add an item in a collection using Linq and C#"

For Example I have same collection:

```
      List<Subscription> subscription = new List<Subscription>
       {
           new Subscription{Type = "Trial", Period = 30 },
           new Subscription{Type = "Free", Period = 90 },
           new Subscription{Type = "Paid", Period = 365 }
       };
```

Now I want to update an item of this list using C# code. Is it possible?

Comment: subscription[0].Type = "ChangedTypeOfFirstItem";

Comment: Updating an item is as simple as getting an item from the list and then performing any updates as necessary.  Is there a specific way you are looking to update a particular item?

Comment: @Reniuz This only works if Subscription is a reference type.  Granted, it would be weird if Subscription were a value type, but it should be noted nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subscription list contains 3 references to 3 Subscription objects. If you update any one of the 3 subscription objects in that list (through whatever means) then the list will reference the updated element.

```
subscription.First(s => s.Period == 30).Trial = "new";
```

Will update the subscription object.. List won't change but it references the same object which has been updated

Answer (score 1):

You create a contextmanager for example `dbManager`

```
var subscription = dbManager.Subscriptions.Single(s => s.Type == "Free");
subscription.Period = 120;
dbManager.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

<_InstanceName>[ItemIndex].<_property>= newValue

Answer (score 0):

To update the first item in your list to a new period you can do this:

```
subscription[ 0 ].Period = 40;
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you wish to update all items in the collection you could achieve this like so,

```
subscription.ForEach(s => s.Period = 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that if Subscription were a value type you'd need to do something like this:

```
Subscription updateMe = subscription[0];
updateMe.Period = 40;
subscription[0] = updateMe;
```

I'd also note that collection names are usually plural, so the list should be named `subscriptions`.  I suppose, however, that this convention loses its value if the developers working on the code are native speakers of a language that doesn't use plurals like that.